# Android Layout Designers

Tags: android, layout

I'm planning on designing quite a complicated app and I find drawing out the general layout of the windows on paper just isn't efficient, is there any useful software that digitizes this process?

I know I could just use the layout designer in Eclipse but it seems a bit clunky. Are there any alternatives?

**Edit:** An example of what I am looking for is [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) but I would prefer a free solution if possible.

Comment: requests for 'what tool should I use' are off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Cordova or Phonegap or Appery.io plus Zepto.js and Jquery Mobile to make a usable walk-through application? (has basic interactions, but no real variables)

Then, you can run it in the emulator and give a real demonstration of some of the basics.

You can copy/paste code from the JQuery site and use their Themer for easy to use CSS. No coding skill really required here.

It would also a give your development team a huge head-start as it is much more clear more than just the desired look and functionality, but a certain degree on the feel (UX) components as well.

Visio / Inkscape / Illustrator are good for making wireframes as well, but I find them to be much more tedious than just doing it in a mobile webview most of the time. Loading images for custom buttons and such is also very easy.

Here is a good example of interactive wireframes using Inkscape: 
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/03/wireframing-inkscape-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

I have used Axure RP Pro and Balsamiq Mockups for mobile wireframes.